# Как поменять ширину отдельной ячейки

Tags: html, css

Есть таблица, ширина первого столбца 30px.
Нужно сделать ячейку `1а` шириной 50px, оставив при этом остальную структуру неизменной. Как это сделать?

```css
table {
   border: solid 1px blue;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   width: 500px;
   height: 100px;
}

td, th {
   border: solid 1px blue;
   padding: 10px;
}
.w21{
   width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <caption>Таблица с заданными размерами</caption>
    <tr>
        <th style="width:30px">1</th>
        <th>2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="special">1a</th>
        <th>2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для таблицы не получится задать разную ширину ячеек, поэтому как например:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.caption {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.table {
   border: solid 1px blue;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

.tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
}

.td {
   border: solid 1px blue;
   border-left: none;
   padding: 10px;
  
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.td:first-child {
  width: 30px;
}

.td.special{
   width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="caption">Таблица с заданными размерами</div>
  
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">1</div>
        <div class="td">2</div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td special">1a</div>
        <div class="td">2</div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">1</div>
        <div class="td">2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Еще костыльный вариант именно для таблицы:

```css
table {
   border: solid 1px blue;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
  table-layout:fixed;
}

tr {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
   border: solid 1px blue;
   padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  
}

tr:last-child td,
tr:last-child th{
  border-bottom: none;
}

td:first-child,
th:first-child {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow:0;
}

.special{
   width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <caption>Таблица с заданными размерами</caption>
    <tr>
        <th style="width:30px">1</th>
        <th>2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="special">1a</th>
        <th>2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>2</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

И еще вариант, почти как e-mail письмо:

```css
table table {
   border: solid 1px blue;
   border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
   max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout:fixed;
}


table table td, 
table table th {
   border: solid 1px blue;
   padding: 10px;  
}

table table td:first-child, 
table table th:first-child {
  width: 30px;
}

table table th.special {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>  
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Таблица с заданными размерами
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
  
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th class="special">1a</th>
          <th>2</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
  
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th>
          <th>2</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Это для wp (woocommerce), там в разделе checkout выводится таблица с данными о заказе, было желание не искать шаблон, а подправить css, видимо не получится(